# Outlook code compile error due to `Application` reference missing

Tags: c#, outlook

I am trying to write some c# code to interact with Outlook 2010. I am currently using [this example from Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff184617.aspx).

My code follows:

```
using System;
using System.Text;          // StringBuilder
using System.Diagnostics;   // Debug

using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

namespace DirectReports
{
    public class Program
    {
        private void GetManagerDirectReports()
        {
            Outlook.AddressEntry currentUser = Application.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry;
            //Outlook.AddressEntry currentUser = Outlook.Application.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry;
            if (currentUser.Type == "EX")
            {
                Outlook.ExchangeUser manager = currentUser.GetExchangeUser().GetExchangeUserManager();
                if (manager != null)
                {
                    Outlook.AddressEntries addrEntries =
                        manager.GetDirectReports();
                    if (addrEntries != null)
                    {
                        foreach (Outlook.AddressEntry addrEntry
                            in addrEntries)
                        {
                            Outlook.ExchangeUser exchUser = addrEntry.GetExchangeUser();
                            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                            sb.AppendLine("Name: " + exchUser.Name);
                            sb.AppendLine("Title: " + exchUser.JobTitle);
                            sb.AppendLine("Department: " + exchUser.Department);
                            sb.AppendLine("Location: " + exchUser.OfficeLocation);
                            Debug.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Microsoft example mentions "If you use Visual Studio to test this code example, you must first add a reference to the Microsoft Outlook 15.0 Object Library component". I am working in Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop. I did not see a version 15.0 object library, but added the version 14.0 one instead (which I think it the right one for Outlook 2010 anyways):

[image: references included]

When I attempt a build, I get the following error:

```
The name 'Application' does not exist in the current context
```

I read a couple of references that indicate `Application` should be part of the above object libraries, but obviously it is not working here. Can someone please suggest what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

You can create a new `Application` object:

```
var appOutlook = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
```

And then use it as:

```
Outlook.AddressEntry currentUser = appOutlook.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry;
```

Comment: thanks, this seems to work so far. But I am not clear why an `Application` object was not needed in the MS example. Can you explain what the difference is?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong project.
When you create a new project in Visual studio, use The Outlook Add-in template.
(Templates -> Visual C# -> Office -> Outlook).

In this code they Application.Session wil work like you expect.

Or you should create a new application object like this.
var outlook = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
And use outlook.Session.

Comment: thanks, the new `Application` object approach seems to work. (The different project type approach may also work, but I did not try it yet.) Can you please explain what the different project type does, and why I would not need an `Application` object with that approach? Given that the MS example did not have an `Application` object specified, I guess that must be what they assumed?

Answer (score -1):

Add the following line at the beginning of the file:

```
 using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
```

Or just prepend any Outlook object declaration with the Outlook alias.

You may find the [C# app automates Outlook (CSAutomateOutlook)](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/CSAutomateOutlook-a3b7bdc9) sample project helpful.

Comment: sorry, that did not seem to work: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._Application.Session.get' But I have not yet read through the link you provided - so the reason may be in there. I will have a closer look.